# Cannot update multiple records in table which has a trigger configured

Tags: sql, triggers

I run the following query:

```
update XFolder
set isdeleted = 1
where XFolder.XFolderID in (select FundRaiseXFolder.XFolderID from FundRaiseXFolder where FundRaiseID = 6233)
```

I am getting following error:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Fippex_UpdateXFolderCacheTableForPrivatePublic, Line 20
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

This used to work fine until I added trigger on table xfolder.

Comment: Is this MS SQLServer? It looks like it is from the format of the error message.

Comment: Probably should show the text of the trigger.

Comment: Yea, problem is in the trigger added by yourself. Let us have a look at its code.